# How to display side by side bar plot as well as stacked bar plot in the same figure in R?

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart, visualization, stacked-chart

I have the following dataset with variables:

1. X_rfhlth : "Good" or "Bad" health
2. X_imprace : "Asian" " White", "Black" etc
3. Sex: Male, Female

I want to create a bar plot for proportions which is stacked as well as side by side.

Each pair of bars will represent a race, the stacked bars will represent good or bad health summing up to 100%. Each pair of bars represents male and female.

How can I approach this? geom_col() allows position="stack" or "dodge" but not both.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use facets. E.g.:

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(factor(vs), mpg, fill = factor(cyl))) + 
  geom_col() + 
  facet_grid(~factor(gear))
```

[image]

Alternatively, plot the interaction. But that is usually less nice:

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(interaction(vs, gear), hp, fill = factor(cyl))) + 
  geom_col()
```

[image]